# How do I set the pdf file name for iframe on the server side of my sveltekit app?

Tags: iframe, svelte, sveltekit

I am trying to name a pdf file that I am getting from a shared file on the network. I read that you can set the file name by setting a 'Content-Disposition" header which I am doing. But this is not saving the file name when I am viewing it in my client side. Here is the server side where I am grabbing a file from a shared computer and sending it to the client. Right now it has some weird file name inside the iframe. I have added the header to name the file how I think it should me named. I am able to console.log the filename but when I download or look at the filename in the properties it does not show what I console.log. Here is the server side:

```
import SMB2 from 'v9u-smb2';

export async function GET({ url }: { url: { searchParams: URLSearchParams } }) {
    const plateID = url.searchParams.get('plateID') || '';

    const smbOptions = {
        share: '\\\\fileName',
        domain: 'Domain Name',
        username: 'Username',
        password: 'Password',
    };

    const smbClient = new SMB2(smbOptions);

    try {
        const filePath = 'PDF\\Piece_TEST_900442A.pdf';

        // Use a Promise to handle the asynchronous file reading operation
        const fileContent = await new Promise<Uint8Array>((resolve, reject) => {
            smbClient.readFile(filePath, function (err, data) {
                if (err) {
                    reject(err);
                } else {
                    resolve(data as Uint8Array);
                }
            });
        });

        // Set the headers for the response
        const headers = new Headers();
        headers.set('Content-Disposition', `inline; filename=${plateID}.pdf`);
        headers.set('Content-Type', 'application/pdf'); // Set the appropriate content type

        // Return the file content as a response
        return new Response(fileContent, { headers });
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error: ', error);
        return new Response(JSON.stringify({ message: error }), { status: 500 });
    } 
}
```

And here is my client side:

```
<script>
    import { onMount } from 'svelte';
    import { goto } from '$app/navigation';

    /**
     * @type {string}
     */
    let pdfUrl;
    /**
     * @type {any}
     */
    let plateID;

    async function showPDF() {
        try {
            const response = await fetch(`api/download?plateID=${plateID}`);

            if (response.ok) {
                const filename = getFilenameFromContentDisposition(response.headers.get('Content-Disposition'));
                console.log('Filename:', filename);

                const blob = await response.blob();
                const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                pdfUrl = url;
            } else {
                console.error('Error:', response.statusText);
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error:', error);
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param {string | null} contentDisposition
     */
    function getFilenameFromContentDisposition(contentDisposition) {
        // @ts-ignore
        const matches = contentDisposition.match(/filename[^;=\n]*=((['"]).*?\2|[^;\n]*)/);
        return matches ? matches[1] : null;
    }

    function handleSubmit() {
        showPDF();
    }

    function navigateToSearch() {
        goto('/');
    }
</script>

<div class="w-full h-full flex justify-center">
    <div class="w-[90%]">
        <div class="flex mt-4 justify-center items-center">
            <!-- Made a form for submitting on enter -->
            <form on:submit|preventDefault={handleSubmit}>
                <div class="group relative">
                    <input
                        class="shadow appearance-none border-2 rounded py-2 px-3 text-gray-700 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline dark:text-white dark:bg-gray-700"
                        id="username"
                        type="text"
                        placeholder="Enter Plate ID"
                        bind:value={plateID}
                        autocomplete="off"
                    />
                    <div
                        class="hidden group-hover:block absolute dark:bg-gray-600 dark:text-white bg-gray-100 text-gray-700 p-4 rounded-md shadow-md z-10"
                    >
                        <p class="relative p-4 bg-gray-200 dark:bg-gray-500 dark:text-white rounded-lg">
                            To get all daughter plates enter first 7 characters
                            <span
                                class="absolute top-0 left-1/2 -translate-y-1/4 transform -translate-x-1/2 w-5 h-5 dark:bg-gray-500 rotate-45 bg-gray-200"
                            />
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
            <button
                class="bg-green-800 hover:bg-green-600 text-white font-bold py-1 px-3 rounded-full disabled:opacity-25 ml-4"
                on:click={handleSubmit}>Search</button
            >
            <button
                class="bg-green-900 hover:bg-green-700 text-white font-bold py-1 px-3 rounded-full ml-6 text-base"
                on:click={navigateToSearch}>Search By Date</button
            >
        </div>
            <main class="w-full h-[90%] mt-2">
                {#if pdfUrl}
                <iframe src={pdfUrl} class="w-[95%] h-full mx-auto" style="border: none;" title="PDF" />
                {:else}
                <p>Loading PDF...</p>
                {/if}
            </main>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here is an example file name
[image]